# Railway.app can't find staticfiles after deployment django app

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I try to deploy my app to Railway.app. App generally works but static files are not found.
I have made collectstatic folder using command `django manage.py collectstatic` as advised in deployment tutorials but it doesn't help.
Any clue what could went wrong ?

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

staticfiles folder is situated in directory that contains menage.py file

deploy logs from railway.apps

```
Not Found: /staticfiles/style.css
Not Found: /staticfiles/base.css
Not Found: /staticfiles/MyImage.png
Not Found: /staticfiles/base.js
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WhiteNoise work for me:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

In your settigs.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE="whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a generic .gitignore check and make sure that your staticfile is passed to your repo, alternative is to find a way to modify the default script that railway runs in deployment and make it run createstatic

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I think its a thing with Railway App, I ended up using Cloudinary to store my static files

```
pip install django-cloudinary-storage
```

Once you have done that, add cloudinary and cloudinary_storage to you installed apps in your settings.py. If you are going to use this package for static and/or media files, make sure that cloudinary_storage is before django.contrib.staticfiles:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cloudinary',
    # ...
]
```

Next, you need to add Cloudinary credentials to settings.py:

```
CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
    'CLOUD_NAME': 'your_cloud_name',
    'API_KEY': 'your_api_key',
    'API_SECRET': 'your_api_secret'
}
```

Then run

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and fixed it using whitenoise:

1. pip install whitenoise
2. set middleware in settings.py to:
   `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',`
3. Add the following, I placed under STATIC_FILES:
   `STATICFILES_STORAGE ='whitenoise.storage.StaticFilesStorage'`
4. Ran python manage.py collectstatic
5. remember to include whitenoise in your requirements.txt file. The nixpax version that worked for me was whitenoise==5.3.0